# Python splitext

Tags: python, path, operating-system, separator

In python, why is `os.path.splitext` using '.' as extension separator instead of `os.extsep`?

Comment: Neither answer has addressed this good question. Does `os.path.splitext` actually use `'.'`, or does it use `os.path.extsep`? The docs say `'.'`.

Comment: @Tom: you can read the definition of `splitext` here: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d3e072083ff3/Lib/posixpath.py#l108, at least for python 3.3 but it didn't change much.

Comment: @mouad - thanks, never had occasion to look at the sources before. So, it does use a hardcoded `'.'` instead of `os.path.extsep`. Seems like one of those bugs that won't be tripped by most people.

Comment: @Tom: Don't you have Python installed? It's all in the `lib` directory...

Comment: @Tim - I think I did know that, but if I don't use something often I often forget it.

Answer (score 5):

`os.extsep` is defined by importing `os.path.extsep`. But you're right, `os.path.splitext()` always uses `.`, regardless of `os.path.extsep`:

From `os.py` (3.2.2):

```
from os.path import (curdir, pardir, sep, pathsep, defpath, extsep, altsep,
    devnull)
```

From `ntpath.py` (which becomes `os.path`)

```
extsep = '.'
[...]
def _get_dot(path):
    if isinstance(path, bytes):
        return b'.'
    else:
        return '.'   # instead of return extsep! [Comment by me, not in source]
[...]
def splitext(p):
    return genericpath._splitext(p, _get_sep(p), _get_altsep(p),
                                 _get_dot(p))
```

Also, from `genericpath.py`:

```
def _get_dot(path):
    if isinstance(path, bytes):
        return b'.'
    else:
        return '.'
```

So `os.path()` does in fact define the extension separator twice.

Now it probably doesn't matter because it's not going to change anytime soon (it's the same on all supported platforms anyway). But in a way, it violates the DRY principle.